# How to upgrade MongoDB 3.6.9 to 4.0 series in different Server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

What are the steps for installing and upgrading MongoDB on a remote server that is either a sharded cluster or has a split configuration? Additionally, how can I establish a connection between MongoDB and another server? Thank you.

Comment: See [Upgrade a Sharded Cluster to 4.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-sharded-cluster/)